# Chrome DevTools Performance tab - does dark red mean frame drop?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the FPS line of the Chrome DevTools Performance tab, i thought that the higher the green bar is - the higher the FPS is (which is good), and if you see a dark red mark that means the frame rate was so low at that point, it probably negatively affected UX.

But given the screenshot below:

[image]

If you look at the middle dark red marker, the green FPS bar is pretty high, which means high FPS. But that particular red mark means really low FPS so i'm not sure why it's showing contradicting information?